# Trying to remove specific strings from text files

Tags: java, string, text, file-io

Im having some trouble getting this function to work, so ill provide abit of context here. All this is, is a button to remove a line out of 3 different text files. It determines the strings to remove by grabbing them from the textFields within the main GUI then searches the relevant files to find the strings. Once the strings are found they are written to a temporary file and flushed.

This code does actually work but only for the first file. The only problem I am having with this chunk of code is that the last too renames wont work for some reason? I need to rename the files back to the originals so the rest of my software will run correctly.

Please can anyone help? :)

```
removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    // TODO
                    String name = reminderNameField.getText();
                    String date = reminderDate.getText();
                    String details = reminderDetailsField.getText();

                    File fileName = new File("reminderNames.txt");
                    File fileDate = new File("reminderDate.txt");
                    File fileDetails = new File("reminderDetails.txt");


                    try {
                    File tempFileN = new File(fileName.getAbsoluteFile() + ".tmp");
                    File tempFileD = new File(fileDate.getAbsoluteFile() + ".tmp");
                    File tempFileC = new File(fileDetails.getAbsoluteFile() + ".tmp");

                    BufferedReader brName = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reminderNames.txt"));
                    BufferedReader brDate = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reminderDate.txt"));
                    BufferedReader brDetails = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reminderDetails.txt"));

                    PrintWriter pwName = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFileN));
                    PrintWriter pwDate = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFileD));
                    PrintWriter pwDetails = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFileC));

                    String lineN = null;
                    String lineD = null;
                    String lineC = null;
                    while ((lineN = brName.readLine()) !=null && (lineD = brDate.readLine()) !=null && (lineC = brDetails.readLine()) !=null) {
                        if(!lineN.trim().equals(name) && !lineD.trim().equals(date) && !lineC.trim().equals(details)) {
                            pwName.println(lineN);
                            pwName.flush();
                            pwDate.println(lineD);
                            pwDate.flush();
                            pwDetails.println(lineC);
                            pwDetails.flush();
                        }
                    }

                    pwName.close();
                    pwDate.close();
                    pwDetails.close();

                    brName.close();
                    brDate.close();
                    brDetails.close();

                    fileName.delete();
                    fileDate.delete();
                    fileDetails.delete();

                    if(!tempFileN.renameTo(fileName)) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot rename file");
                    }
                    if(!tempFileD.renameTo(fileDate)) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot rename file date");
                    }
                    if(!tempFileC.renameTo(fileDetails)) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot rename file details");
                    }
```

*** UPDATE ***
Written this method which does work, however for some reason it only works for one file? can anyone tell me why?

```
public void removeReminder(File a, String search) throws IOException {

File tempFile = new File(a.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
String line = null;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.trim().equals(search)) {
        pw.println(line);
        pw.flush();
    }
}
pw.close();
br.close();

a.delete();

tempFile.renameTo(a);
```

}

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you have a single function that processes a single file at a time and just iterate over the three files?

Comment: Im starting to think that would be alot easier, but been having loads of trouble trying to get it to work? How would you recommend going about this?

Comment: Write a method that does it for one file. Make sure that works first. Once it does, it's likely that either (a) your problem will magically disappear, or (b) the problem will magically become obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the help dave. Think I was just staring at one piece to long. I did what you said and it worked! thank you very much for your time! :)

Comment: Methods-that-do-too-much are difficult to reason about; decomposing problems usually makes them significantly easier to solve :) Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read texts from file with:

```
 public static String readAllText(String filename) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).forEach(sb::append);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can remove or change with .replace:

```
String file1 = readAllText("temp.tmp"); file1.replace(fileName,"");
```